# How do I get the value of a boolean from a database field?

Tags: c#, database, winforms

```
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = Lib.SqlConnection;
            MembersDataTable = new DataTable();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT MemberId, FirstName, Surname, Description as Grade, DateOfBirth, MedicalInformation , Paid, Permissions FROM Members m inner join Grade g on m.Grade = g.grade";
            cmd.CommandText += " WHERE MemberId = " + _MemberId;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            adapter.Fill(MembersDataTable);FirstName.Text = MembersDataTable.Rows[0]["FirstName"].ToString();

            Surname.Text = MembersDataTable.Rows[0]["Surname"].ToString();
            GradeComboBox.Text = MembersDataTable.Rows[0]["Grade"].ToString();
            DOBPicker.Text = MembersDataTable.Rows[0]["DateOfBirth"].ToString().Replace("00:00:00", "");
            Medical.Text = MembersDataTable.Rows[0]["MedicalInformation"].ToString();
```

This is what I have so far, but I want to add in a checkbox called paid, which will get the value of paid from the main database and then if it is ticked in the main database then this new tickbox will be ticked will be ticked when this form is loaded.(Sorry if this is not clear, I don't know how better to explain it. If you need more information I can try to provide it)

Comment: What is the data type of `Paid` in your database? `BIT`? `INT`? `CHAR(1)`? (And which database are you using?)

Comment: You asked about inserting but you've shown a `SELECT` query. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: It is a bit datatype, also the select statement is so that I can get that data out from the database, sorry I should've explained, this is for updating the records which is done later on, thanks!

Comment: I tried using `if(MembersDataTable.Rows[0]["Paid"] != null)
                {
                    PaidBox.Checked = true;
                }` but this just makes it checked all the time.

Comment: It is currently nullable, but that will change once I can make it work properly, and when I try it with a 1 or a 0, it says that the object can't be coverted to a bool... And Yes I should be getting a bool, but I don't know how to store it the same way as the others are stored.

Comment: @madreflection...you are right. SqlClient treats a bit as bool...I forgot that..cause Im always converting the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your checkbox like this with a ternary operator
[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

```
PaidBox.Checked = (bool)MembersDataTable.Rows[0]["Paid"];
```

Comment: this gives the message "Possible unintended reference comparison". Does there need to be something else with it?

Comment: @Alex Since its a nullable field...try the cast with (bool?)